# Using a tuple to map values between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

If I need to map one value between two dataframes, and get 'FD' value from row where Round = 1 an Id is 262:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Round':1,'ID':262,'FD':30,
                     'Round':2,'ID':262,'FD':20}, index=[0])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Round':1, 'Opponent':262,
                    'Round':2, 'Opponent':262},index=[0])
```

I have tried to map with:

```
df2['P_GS_by_FD'] = f2['Opponent'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['FD'])
```

`df2` Expected output:

```
  Round    Opponent  P_GS_by_FD
      1      262          30
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output ? , Also you df1 can not be created ~

Comment: please refer to my edit

Comment: Still unclear to me ....

Comment: @BEN_YO I guess I expecte output was wrong

Comment: Why we did not pick round 2 ?

Comment: because I need values from Round 1, with that team Id. Ids will be repeatd 40 times, but (round + id) is a unique tuple, and I need the cell value from that particular row

Comment: I think you need to uses merge to merge on Round and ID/Opponent.

Comment: what if there's Round column in df2 as well? see my edit

Comment: I am not sure my answer address the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Then we need create the round in df2 as well

```
df2['Round'] = df.groupby('Opponent').cumcount()+1
yourdf = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Id' : 'Opponent'}), on = ['Opponent','Round'], how = 'left')
```

Base on your update

```
yourdf = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'ID' : 'Opponent'}), on = ['Opponent','Round'], how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `drop_duplicates`

this would select 'Round 1' rows

```
df1.drop_duplicates('Id', keep='first')


df2['P_GS_by_FD'] = df2['Opponent'].map(df1.drop_duplicates('Id', keep='first').set_index('Id')['FD'])
```

(I think your example df1, df2 would make only one row instead of two)

Comment: problem is that in real life scenario, ID is repeated many many times, so keep first or last last is not an option...

Comment: But didn't you say that round + id is unique? then how about selecting the round first then select the id?
`df1[df1['Round'] ==1]['Id']`